# Original Custom Model object of fragment A is being affected by changes in another Fragment B

Tags: android, object, android-fragments, bundle

Hi I am stuck in a issue. I am sending a model object from FragmentA to FragmentB via Bundle and changing model value in FragmentB. When I come back to FragmentA and checks model value, it is showing the changed value instead of original one. So How can I get the original ModelObject's data?

Here is my code

**FragmentA**

```
FragmentB blankFragment2 = new FragmentB();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("DATA", arraylist.get(0));   //CustomModel of arrayList
blankFragment2.setArguments(bundle);
((MainActivity) getActivity()).push(blankFragment2);
```

**FragmentB**

```
modelObject = getArguments().getParcelable("DATA");
modelObject.setAge("28");
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to make a separate Object for both if you want to get Original same as Fragment A contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a clone of your model to other Fragment.

See this [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning)